# Помогите разобраться

Tags: пунктуация

Уважаемые участники, скажите пожалуйста, в данных предложениях перед тире нужно ставить запятую и если - да, то почему? Заранее спасибо.
1) А ещё машина в любой момент может заглохнуть(,) - это всего лишь вопрос времени. 
2) То, что она ещё едет(,) - это чудо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **А ещё машина в любой момент может заглохнуть — это всего лишь вопрос времени.**

Тире в бессоюзном  сложном предложении (БСП).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

9. Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения представляет собой присоединительное предложение, перед ней ставится тире (возможно вставить слово ***это***, которое иногда имеется в самом предложении): На стене ни одного образа — дурной знак (Л.);

   2) **То, что она ещё едет, — это чудо.** Здесь ***это*** в роли связки перед сказуемым.

Сравнить:

То, что она еще едет, является чудом.

Тот факт (какой?), что она еще едет, — это чудо. Обособление придаточного.

**Независимая** постановка запятой и тире.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, то есть во втором предложении могу поставить запятую + тире?

Comment: Там нужно поставить запятую и тире, так как запятая закрывает придаточное. А в первом предложении тире обозначает  присоединительную  связь двух простых предложений в БСП, там достаточно только тире.

Comment: Я вам так благодарна. Спасибо...